# Calling helper function inside android application project from a library project

Tags: function, android, library-project

I have an android application project. I have created a library project and added reference in the application project. Now I need to call/access certain functions/class/methods that is there in the application project from the library project. How can I do that ?

Comment: it's quite easy i think... you just have to create object of classes and call methods directly .for this you just need to import packages

Comment: It would be better if you could describe what you've done and what you struggled with.

Comment: its not about calling a method of one class from another. The problem is I am trying to call a method in a Android application project from a Library project. I can't import the application package inside the library project to create an object and call method.

Comment: So you're using your android application project as a reference for your library project but you're not really adding your application to the library project ?

Comment: add library project in android application

Comment: @Mitul I think he's doing the reverse, he aint clear....

Comment: No, I added the library project to the app. But for some reason I need to access some of the classes there in the app in the library too. i successfully referenced the library from the application and accesses the resources there in the library. Now I need the reverse too.

Comment: I believe you need to put the files that you want to access to a new project and then have it referenced in your library cause accessing your existing project would bring a circular dependency.. I am not sure this would work but its worth a try....

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Create an interface in the library that defines the functions you would like the library to call. Have the application implement the interface and then register the implementing object with the library. Then the library can call the application through that object.

In the library, declare the interface and add the registration function:

```
public class MyLibrary {
  public interface AppInterface {
    public void myFunction();
  }

  static AppInterface myapp = null;

  static void registerApp(AppInterface appinterface) {
    myapp = appinterface;
  }
}
```

Then in your application:

```
public class MyApplication implements MyLibrary.AppInterface {
  public void myFunction() {
    // the library will be able to call this function
  }

  MyApplication() {
    MyLibrary.registerApp(this);
  }
}
```

You library can now call the app through the AppInterface object:

```
// in some library function
if (myapp != null) myapp.myFunction();
```

Comment: made my day a lot easier.. Can give only one upvote.. awesome.

Answer (score 0):

You can just create the object of that particular class and then you can directly call that method or variable.

```
class A{
  public void methodA(){
    new B().methodB();
    //or
    B.methodB1();
  }
}

class B{
  //instance method
  public void methodB(){
  }
  //static method
  public static  void methodB1(){
  }
}
```

Don't forget to import the necessary packages.

Comment: I am trying to call from a library project, hence I am not able to import the package of the parent application, where the class and associated methods are present.